# Not able to run `build_runner` in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, flutter-hive, build-runner

I've trying to run `build_runner` to generate hive adapter files but I get running into this issue and here the error message

```
dart pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
Building package executable... 
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner_core-7.2.2/lib/src/logging/build_for_input_logger.dart:13:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'BuildForInputLogger' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Logger.onLevelChanged
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class BuildForInputLogger implements Logger {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/logging-1.2.0/lib/src/logger.dart:162:22: Context: 'Logger.onLevelChanged' is defined here.
  Stream<Level?> get onLevelChanged {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.1.11/lib/src/build_script_generate/bootstrap.dart:76:40: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError'.
      final error = e[0] as Object? ?? NullThrownError();
```

here's my `pubspec.yaml` file:-

```
name: sutra_ecommerce
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using flutter pub publish. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running flutter pub upgrade --major-versions. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run flutter pub outdated.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
  provider: ^6.1.1
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.1
  dio: ^4.0.0
  get: ^4.6.6
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  dio_http_cache: ^0.3.0
  chucker_flutter: 
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
  hive: ^2.2.3
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  easy_stepper: ^0.8.3
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.2
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  date_picker_timeline:
  flutter_pay_upi: ^0.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  build_runner: ^2.1.11
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the analysis_options.yaml file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/lotties/


flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/dilicia-logo.jpeg"

    

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

My flutter doctor output is:-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64,
    locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)            
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

How can I run `build_runner` what might be the issue here, I look into similar questions, but I'm able to find a proper solution to this?